# Removing a script when on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, viewport

I am creating a webpage with jInvertscroll. However, this has no mobile support (yet). So i am trying all kinds of smaller scripts to remove this.

So far i have gotten to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var isDesktop = (function() {
return !('ontouchstart' in window)
|| !('onmsgesturechange' in window);
})();

window.isDesktop = isDesktop;
if( isDesktop ){ 

(function($) {
var numberOfdivs = $('.front').children('.photo').length;
var frontwidth = (numberOfdivs) * 833;
console.log(frontwidth);
$(".front").css("width", frontwidth);

$.jInvertScroll(['.scroll'],
{
width: (frontwidth),
onScroll: function(percent) {
console.log(percent);
}
});
}(jQuery));
}
});
```

However, this does not work. I have also tried using an if/else statement to trigger on viewport width. Didnt do the magic either.

Any tips?

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

[enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) is a lightweight, pure JavaScript library for responding to CSS media queries. You can use it like so:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width:45rem)", {
    // You code you want to run above the breakpoint here
});
```